# The largest Thursday number

Tags: mathematics, primes

A Thursday number is a number  where any three consecutive digits make a prime, and all such primes formed are distinct.

For example, 13739 is a Thursday number because 137, 373, and 739 are all distinct primes.

**Find the largest Thursday number.** (Preferably without using a program)

P.S. I know today is not yet Thursday, but I may not be able to come online tomorrow.

Comment: some people do not seem to like the number puzzles looking at the downvotes. Personally, I like them :)

Comment: Are leading zeroes allowed? for example: would 10113 be allowed because 101, 011 and 113 are prime?

Comment: @IvoBeckers Even if they are it will hardly be useful, since they can only be used in the first two digits.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it is

> 9419919379773971911373313179

containing these primes

> 941-419-199-991-919-193-937-379-797-977-773-739-397-971-719-191-911-113-137-373-733-331-313-131-317-179

I wrote a computer program for this that brute forced it. Of course computer programs are prone to errors but I believe it's right.

Comment: Sorry for the many edits. had some bugs in my code, but now I truly believe this is my final answer

Comment: I wrote a program to prove you wrong. Unfortunately, it only confirmed your answer. So +1.

Answer (score 2):

> 76199197739719373311313797

**Work still in progress**

Same as with the *Wednesday number*, we can only use 1, 3, 7, and 9 in primes, except for the first one, so we only have 30 primes that we can use:

```
113 131 137 139 173 179 191 193 197 199 
311 313 317 331 337 373 379 397 
719 733 739 773 797 
911 919 937 971 977 991 997
```

Same as with the *Wednesday number* we should make a longest number with them. Observing the numbers gives us the following:

|  | Starts: | Ends: |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 13 | 3 | 2 |
| 17 | 2 | 1 |
| 19 | 4 | 2 |
| 31 | 3 | 2 |
| 33 | 2 | 1 |
| 37 | 2 | 3 |
| 39 | 1 | 2 |
| 71 | 1 | 1 |
| 73 | 2 | 3 |
| 77 | 1 | 1 |
| 79 | 1 | 2 |
| 91 | 2 | 2 |
| 93 | 1 | 1 |
| 97 | 2 | 4 |
| 99 | 2 | 1 |

Where column *Starts* means that a prime starts with that number, *Ends* means that the prime ends with that number and numbers are just # of occurrences. Finding a 1 - 1 pairs we can immediately say, that they come after each other:

71, 77, 93:
9**71**9, 9**77**3 and 1**93**7

After that it's just a bit of playing around trying to find the longest number. It will consist out of 23 3-digit primes(taking the sum of the lowest of each row in the table), so 25 digits long.

Comment: Well, you do need to check if the resulting number actually is prime...

Comment: @TimCouwelier that isn't a requirement

Comment: @TimCouwelier why should I? It doesn't say so in the question

Comment: @Novarg - It appears I got a bit over-ambitious. You're right. It would make this puzzle ALOT harder though.

Comment: @TimCouwelier Especially "without using a program" (quoting OP)